# CentOS yum repository bad Header V4 RSA/SHA1 signature

Tags: repository, centos, rpm, gpg, yum

I was coping with many problems to get stuck with this one.

I have installed yum repository on server (CentOS 5.6) with:

```
createrepo -v -s sha yumrepo/
```

sha is used due to solution to my earlier problem I have found: my reposistory was not accepted. 
(`[Errno -3] Error performing checksum` )

generated gpg key with:

```
gpg --gen-key
```

sign package with (package was not created on server):

```
rpm --addsign mypackage-1.0-1.i386.rpm
```

check if was signed properly:

```
rpm -vv --checksig mypackage-1.0-1.i386.rpm 
D: loading keyring from pubkeys in /var/lib/rpm/pubkeys/*.key
D: couldn't find any keys in /var/lib/rpm/pubkeys/*.key
D: loading keyring from rpmdb
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages rdonly mode=0x0
D: locked   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Name rdonly mode=0x0
D:  read h#     205 Header sanity check: OK
D: added key gpg-pubkey-c105b9de-4e0fd3a3 to keyring
D:  read h#     313 Header sanity check: OK
D: added key gpg-pubkey-ebb3d90e-4ee5e6e8 to keyring
D: Using legacy gpg-pubkey(s) from rpmdb
D: Expected size:         3126 = lead(96)+sigs(528)+pad(0)+data(2502)
D:   Actual size:         3126
mypackage-1.0-1.i386.rpm:
    Header V4 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID ebb3d90e: OK
    Header SHA1 digest: OK (6d131be3c792fcc99da662f432c33facc86efc56)
    V4 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID ebb3d90e: OK
    MD5 digest: OK (76cfe98c4128d45da894a2b5b970e703)
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Name
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages
```

and exported my public key with:

```
gpg --armor --output MY-GPG-KEY --export 'MYNAME'
```

On client (CentOS 5.6 too) I have created file /etc/yum.repos.d/myrepo.repo with following content:

```
[myrepo]
name=myrepo
baseurl=https://login:pass@address.to.my.repo
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://login:pass@address.to.my.repo/MY-GPG-KEY
protect=1
```

than as root I have run:

```
yum clean all
yum install mypackage
```

and get an error:

```
Downloading Packages:
mypackage-0.1-1.noarch.rpm                                | 3.0 kB     00:00     
error: rpmts_HdrFromFdno: Header V4 RSA/SHA1 signature: BAD, key ID ebb3d90e
```

While:

```
rpm -q gpg-pubkey
gpg-pubkey-e8562897-459f07a4
gpg-pubkey-217521f6-45e8a532
gpg-pubkey-ebb3d90e-4ee5e6e8
```

What should I do to have my package securely installed ?

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is on this page :
http://adminotes.blogspot.fr/2011/12/centos-6-rpm-sign-problem-v4-signatures.html

In summary, v4 signature are used by default in Centos 6, but Centos 5 only supports v3.

Adding `--force-v3-sigs` flag in your `%__gpg_sign_cmd` will makes it work.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is the gpg key. There is a [bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=436812) due to which broken signatures are created. I suggest editing myrepo.repo and setting  `gpgcheck=1`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem in CentOS 6. 
I thought I would document my solution for people like me, who land up here.

I had CentOS 6.0 with old version of rpm of ca-certificates viz. ca-certificates-2010.63-3.el6.noarch.

While installing an rpm using yum, I got below error :
error: rpmts_HdrFromFdno: Header V4 DSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 35511c46: BAD

By comparing rpm packages with a working server & checking history of commands, I was able to narrow down the problem to the above package.

After installing the latest version (ca-certificates-2017.2.14-65.0.1.el6_9.noarch) and its dependencies using yum, I was able to install the rpm which I was attempting to install in the first place.

As a side note, the nss-softtoken packages were updated while updating the ca-certificates package. I'm not very sure if that is what solved the problem, as documented at https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=50775.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
$ sudo rpm --addsign zstd-1.4.4-1.cl8.x86_64.rpm
zstd-1.4.4-1.cl8.x86_64.rpm:
gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on homedir '/home/rongtao/.gnupg'
gpg: writing to 'zstd-1.4.4-1.cl8.x86_64.rpm.sig'
gpg: pinentry launched (49593 curses 1.1.0 /dev/pts/0 xterm-256color -)
gpg: RSA/SHA256 signature from: "3F2FA11D3D67D70B Rong Tao <rongtao@cestc.cn>"
gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on homedir '/home/rongtao/.gnupg'
gpg: writing to 'zstd-1.4.4-1.cl8.x86_64.rpm.sig'
gpg: RSA/SHA256 signature from: "3F2FA11D3D67D70B Rong Tao <rongtao@cestc.cn>"

$ rpm -qpi zstd-1.4.4-1.cl8.x86_64.rpm 
error: zstd-1.4.4-1.cl8.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 3d67d70b: BAD
error: zstd-1.4.4-1.cl8.x86_64.rpm: not an rpm package (or package manifest)
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/417719)